# Counting element properties in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a vector of objects, and I'd like to count how many of them contain a certain property.

I'm fairly sure this can be done with the STL but I couldn't find an example. I could of course use a loop and count myself, but I need to do this many times and I'd prefer a concise way of doing this.

I'm looking to do something like the pseudo code below

```
class MyObj {
public:
    std::string name;
}

std::vector<MyObj> objects
int calledJohn = count(objects,this->name,"jonn")
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count

Comment: A little google really goes a long way sometimes. Just look at the examples in the link Mat provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to count *how many* objects have a certain property, `std::count_if` is the way to go. `std::count_if` takes a range to iterate over and the functor object that will determine if the object has the value:

```
auto calledJohn = std::count_if(std::begin(objects), std::end(objects),
                           [] (const MyObj& obj) { return obj.name == "John"; });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)

```
auto n = std::count_if(objects.begin(), objects.end(),
                       [](const MyObj& o) { return o.name == "jonn";});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function `std::count_if` in the algorithm header that does exactly that for you. You have to provide an iterator range (so in your case `objects.begin` and `objects.end`) and a predicate that could be a lambda function or any other callable object:

```
auto number = std::count_if(objects.begin(), objects.end(), [](const MyObj &object){if(/*your condition*/){return true;}});
```